# Alternative solutions when the symlink() function is disabled on a live Laravel website

Tags: php, laravel

I've been a looking for solution to create a symlink in my public_html folder however my hosting provider has disabled this function when I try to use it and I'm pretty sure they are the only who can change using the WHM panel. I've seen suggestions by using SSH but I am unsure how to do this, is there anyway round this issue or do I need to contact my hosting provider? Thank you.

Comment: I would strongly suggest to give ssh a chance. It's a great skill to learn and have anyway, if you are building webapps. Maybe start by searching through your hosting providers help section, to find out more about how to connect.

Comment: I have been doing some research about this and finally got a symlink to create thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In CPanel which is what I'm using you can setup cron jobs which I didn't know, you can then use this command ln -s /path/to/target /path/to/shortcut that creates a symlink without using the symlink function which is disabled. Make sure to delete the command otherwise it will create duplicate symlinks.